# Google API Contacts : how to get Frequently contacted contacts

Tags: c#, google-api

I'm getting an issue with Google Api Contacts like below:

I want to get contacts by some conditions such as :  how to get Frequently contacted contacts.

Here is my code:

```
var contacts = new List<ContactDTO>();
                var query = new 

    ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
                    query.NumberToRetrieve = 500;
                    query.FeedFormat = AlternativeFormat.Atom;
                    //query.Query = "???"
                    Feed<Google.Contacts.Contact> feed = _contactsRequest.Get<Google.Contacts.Contact>(query);
```

I don't what Query should I use? how to use the ContactsQuery.query? Please help me ! many thanks!

Comment: please remove NumberToRetrieve parameter or set it to default value. by doing that most probably you will only get Frequent contacts

Comment: Could you please show me how to query contacts by some conditions such as Email = "xxx"?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?